# Leaflet Legend needs to pull value for no data

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have tried replacing many pieces of the strings in the legend javascript to make the first color field the same color as the no value for the data. I am assuming I need to add an exception to the first rule but I can't figure it out. I started with the leaflet tuturial for choropleth maps and have gotten this far. This is the last real piece I need to get the map fully functional. Basically wanting the no data value, countries that are not colored or highlighted, and first field in legend to be grey like the map shows, not the green second value as is shown.

```
var legend = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});

                legend.onAdd = function (map) {

                    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend'),
                        grades = [0, 0.00001, 0.7300001, 2.9900001, 6.700001],
                        labels = [],
                        from, to;

                    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
                        from = grades[i];
                        to = grades[i + 1];

                        labels.push(
                            '<i style="background:' + getColor(from + '1' ) + '"></i> ' +
                            from + (to ? '&ndash;' + to : '&ndash;43.89303638'));
                    } //changed '1' to get right colors on the legend but first field is still second green, not sure why??

                    div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
                    return div;
                };

                legend.addTo(map);
```

This is the piece that fills the colors of the countries by value as is set up now which is functioning correctly.

```
function getColor(d) {
                 return d > 6.700001     ? '#D7191C' :
                        d > 2.9900001    ? '#FDAE61' :
                        d > 0.7300001    ? '#A6D96A' :
                        d > 0.00001      ? '#1A9641' :

                                           '#E9E9E9';
                }

                function style(feature) {
                    return {
                        weight: 2,
                        opacity: 1,
                        color: 'white',
                        dashArray: '3',
                        fillOpacity: 0.7,
                        fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.UNdata_CO2_20151106_191526521_Value)//changed value from value above in blue
                    };
                }
```

Here is a link to [my webpage](http://students.washington.edu/sbuffor/lab3.html)!

I added a note regarding my last change, before that it was showing two grey fields then dark green, light green, and orange without showing red for highest values...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop in the `legend.onAdd` function is generating the colors and labels automatically from the `grades` array, but you can simply add another label of your own before or after the loop. Assuming that `#E9E9E9` is your undefined color, it would go like this:

```
labels.push('<i style="background: #E9E9E9"></i> ' + 'undefined');
```

Put this just before the loop if you want to add the undefined field at the top of the legend, or just after the loop if you want to add it to the end. Here is an example fiddle showing this method at work with some random circle markers:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/4aqfdz1d/

Comment: That worked and was very easy to fix, I learned a lot in this example. I knew there should be a way to add in an expression to create a no data field but none of my attempts worked. Thanks.